# Find a specific day of week based on a date

Tags: php

I would like to be able to find the date which "Sunday" falls on for a given date, formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.

... How would this be achieved in PHP?

Comment: I don't understand the question... Do you mean you want to find the "next" Sunday when given a date?  For example, if I give you 2011-07-04 (today) you'd like to return 2011-07-10 (the next upcoming Sunday)?

Comment: @JaredCobb: That's because there *is* no question.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to find out the date of "Sunday" within the same week.  So if the date was 2011-07-04, it should return 2011-07-03.

Comment: using the day of the week algo `(2 * ( 3 - ((Y div 100) mod 4)) + ( Y mod 100 ) + ( Y div 4 ) + monthlookup[M] + D ) mod 7 = day of the week`, which gives you 0=sunday 1=monday, etc. You can just subtract that number from the days, and you'll get the "previous" sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime() may help you, it accepts GNU-Date-input-formats  like `"next Sunday"`

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday',strtotime("2011-07-04 Z")));
```

Comment: How would you do "current Sunday"?  So that if today is Sunday, it will return today's date, or if it is Monday, it will return yesterday's date?

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks so much!

Comment: for this echo date('l Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday',strtotime("2011-07-02 Z")))."<br>";
    echo date('l Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday',strtotime("2011-07-03 Z")))."<br>";
    echo date('l Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday',strtotime("2011-07-04 Z")))."<br>";  i am having this incorrect anwsers Sunday 2011-07-03
Sunday 2011-07-03
Sunday 2011-07-03

Comment: Please keep in mind: some people in the world(e.g. me) are used to assume that a week starts with a monday, so for me the sunday of this week is 2011-07-10

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function for php.

Comment: You could write a short example ;) your link doens't answer the question. To find the startday you need a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a library that does this, then:

1. Come up with a reference date (January 1, 1970?) for which you know the day of the week.
2. Calculate the number of days between the reference date and your given date.
3. Take that answer modulo 7.
4. Convert to a day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a full example with multiples values
it is for PHP or any other lenguage that uses epoch time (or similar)

```
<?php

function prevSunday($paramDay){
    $aDay = 24*60*60;
    $aWeek = $aDay * 7;

    $sunday = $aDay + $paramDay - (($paramDay - 3 * $aDay) % $aWeek);

    return $sunday;
}

$randDay   = 1309819423 + rand(0, 9000000);            //   this contanis a random day (and hours, minutes, seconds)
$aSaterday = strtotime("20110702");
$aSunday   = strtotime("20110703");
$aMonday   = strtotime("20110704");

echoTwoDays($aSuterday, prevSunday($aSuterday));
echoTwoDays($aSunday,   prevSunday($aSunday));
echoTwoDays($aMonday,   prevSunday($aMonday));
/* echoes
day1: Saturday 20110702
day2: Sunday 20110626

day1: Sunday 20110703
day2: Sunday 20110703

day1: Monday 20110704
day2: Sunday 20110703     
*/
echoTwoDays($randDay,   prevSunday($randDay));   // echoes a random date and perv sunday


function echoTwoDays ($day1, $day2) {
    echo "day1: " . date("l Ymd", $day1) ."<br>";      // remove l as your request
    echo "day2: " . date("l Ymd", $day2) ."<br><br>";  // remove l as your request
}

function prevSunday($paramDay){
    $aDay = 24*60*60;
    $aWeek = $aDay * 7;

    $sunday = $aDay + $paramDay - (($paramDay - 3 * $aDay) % $aWeek);

    return $sunday;
}

?>
```

Comment: this contemplates "current Sunday" as "today"